# Where is the Spotlight .app file located?

Tags: spotlight

I want to use some custom keybindings to access spotlight using [skhd](https://github.com/koekeishiya/skhd) and I  need the location of the binary or `.app` file to do so. Where can I find it?

Comment: What's preventing you from just adding the key commands in prefs?

Answer (score 1):

The bundle is located here, but opening it does not cause Spotlight to appear:

/System/Library/CoreServices/Spotlight.app

Comment: If that's the case, is there a terminal command that show the spotlight?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the answer to that question